# Можно ли распарсить html документ с java-script

Tags: php, javascript, html, qt, qt5

Ситуация следующая. Сайт keepa.com я беру ввожу поиск товара (загружаю html стр. с помощью Qt QNetworkAccessManager короче загружаю стр. с таким адресом: 
[https://keepa.com/#!search/1-AmazonBasics HDMI Input to DVI Output Adapter Cable - 6 Feet (Latest Standard)](https://keepa.com/#!search/1-AmazonBasics%20HDMI%20Input%20to%20DVI%20Output%20Adapter%20Cable%20-%206%20Feet%20(Latest%20Standard))  )

Беда в том что если в браузере наверное отрабатывает java-script, то в ответе я получаю другой html который я не могу распарсить, ведь там нет результатов поиска, можно ли с этим что-то сделать, чтобы получить html стр с отработанным java-script (с результатами поиска).

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону PhantomJS(http://phantomjs.org/), либо библиотеки jsdom(https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Comment: PhantomJS(phantomjs.org) лучше не пользоваться меня там забанили нав из-за этого. А что на счет QWebView или что то типа этого?

Comment: если забанили - значит вы неправильно использовали. Это же как обычный браузер, скорее всего вы не установили заголовок user-agent, поэтому отправлялся дефотлтный, в котором есть упоминание в PhantomJS

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать QtWebView для первичной подгрузки страниц, если, конечно, вам понравится браузер в вашем приложении. :)